# SSL Certificate configuration for Jboss EAP 7.2 & IIS?

Tags: iis, jboss, ssl-certificate

I am still new with this application - server ssl configuration thingy and getting a bit confused with it. Therefore, I need some opinion from the experts here.

Right now, we have **one development server**. This is where we have **iis, jboss eap and mysql**. Currently, we are accessing our **web application via the public ip from our own devices (client).**

However, since we don't have any SSL certification, the web browser will **indicates that the public ip is not secure.**

I was thinking to purchase the ssl certificate and have our **own custom domain like devsyste.company.com.**

When I read few documentation on SSL configuration, I was confused between iis and jboss eap. I am not sure whether I need to configure the SSL using iis or JBoss standalone configuration ?

Do i need to purchase 2 ssl certificates and configure it using both iis and JBoss respectively ?

Below are some documentation that I've read:

https://www.digicert.com/kb/csr-creation-ssl-installation-iis-10.htm

https://www.ssldragon.com/blog/install-an-ssl-certificate-on-jboss-server/

Comment: As a Red Hat Jboss customer, your first contact should be Red Hat customer support, https://access.redhat.com/support/customer-service

Comment: What is your development server? iis or something else? if it is iis, you need an iis ssl certificate.

Comment: @samwu I am running on Microsoft Windows Server 2019 which has IIS with it. However, the application itself is using JBoss EAP.